# Dynamically passing correct number of parameters to class constructor

Tags: php, mysqli

I do this here:

```
public function fetch($className) 
{ 
   $rows = array();
   while($r = $this->result->fetch_object() { 
      $rows[] = new $className($r);
   }
   return $rows;
}
```

Constructor

```
class User
{
   public $dbh;
   public $row; 
   public function __construct($dbh, $row = null) 
   {
      $this->dbh = $dbh;
      $this->row = $row;
   }
   public function getAll()
   { 
      return $this->dbh->query('SELECT * FROM users')->fetchAll();
   }
   public function getFirstName()
   {
      return $this->row->first_name;
   }
}
```

This is all good and well if my class constructor only has ONE parameter.

How do I make this dynamic so that I can have other parameters in my constructor. Hope this makes sense.

Any help would be awesome :-)

Comment: where is your construct function

Comment: added @Akintunde

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Well, it really does depend on what is your general code style. For example. I don't like using `new` near my SQL code. It seems to much of SRP violation.

What I tend to do looks kinda like this:

```
public function applyValues($instance, array $parameters)
{
    foreach ((array) $parameters as $key => $value) {
        $method = 'set' . str_replace('_', '', $key);
        if (method_exists($instance, $method)) {
            $instance->{$method}($value);
        }
    }
}
```

I personally think that it is a hack, but it works well with how rest of my code gets designed.

---

And if you are using PHP 5.6+, you can use [variadics](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

That would look something like:

```
public function fetch($className) 
{ 
   $rows = array();
   while($parameters = $this->result->fetch_object() { 
      $rows[] = new $className(...$parameters);
   }
   return $rows;
}
```

But this approach will be really fragile and will require strict order in the `$parameters` array.

---

There is also third option: design your code in such a way, that you have something like `populate()` method in all of your domain entities. But that seems like a bad idea for  the same reason why entities should not contain their own factories.